# Debug log with sencha architect / sencha touch / phonegap not working

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I just run out a problem while developing on a Sencha Touch 2.3 project. Here my environnement :

- OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)
- Sencha Architect 3.0
- Sencha Touch 2.3.0
- Phonegap 3.1.0­-0.15.0

I tried to build a native app with phonegap for iOS with some logs in xCode but it only works for the first build.. Follow these steps to reproduce the problem :

1. Create blank project in Sencha Architect and name it "SenchaArchitectTest"
2. In app.js file and launch method, add : console.log("App launch debug");
3. Open a terminal and navigate to your project folder
4. Run the following command : "sencha phonegap init com.sencha.test-­architect SenchaArchitectTest"
5. Navigate to phonegap folder : cd phonegap
6. Add the phonegap console plugin : "phonegap local plugin add [https://git­wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova­plugin­console.git](https://git%C2%ADwip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova%C2%ADplugin%C2%ADconsole.git)"
7. Build the app with phonegap
8. Open the project in xCode and launch it

At this point, you can see the “App launch debug” log in the xCode console. Follow the next steps :

1. Add a new log in the app.js : console.log("Second app launch debug");
2. Rebuild the app with phone gap
3. Re­open the project in xCode and launch it

And now, There is no more log..

**The strangest thing about this, is that if I had edited the app.js file with TextEdit for example, both logs would be visible correctly..**

Moreover, if I try to not use phonegap and use the iOS simulator directly from Sencha Architect, I can't see any log too.

Can you help me to resolve this issue ? It's complicated to debug a code without logs ;)

Comment: Hope you're cross posting this to the relevant sencha.com/forum group - that's where the team hangs out

Comment: Yes, but the sencha forum does not care for the moment ;)